# Using Charindex to Find Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, charindex

I have inherited a query that simply matches the PAYMENT_DETAILS field of one table to the PAYMENT_DETAILS field of a second table. It looks to see if the data in the first PAYMENT_DETAILS field is anywhere in the other:

```
left outer join payroll_class P on        
 charindex(P.payment_details,B.PAYMENT_DETAILS) > 0
```

I simply want to identify the correct way to do the reverse of this. I want only the records from the first table whose PAYMENT_DETAILS do not match in any way to the PAYMENT_DETAILS of the second table.

I tried using:

```
left outer join dimpayroll_classification P on        
charindex(P.payment_details,B.PAYMENT_DETAILS) = 0
```

but this did not return the desired results - I'm not sure if this makes sense logically. Then I used a subquery:

```
WHERE customer NOT in (
                      select customer from table b
                      left outer join dimpayroll_classification P on        
                      charindex(P.payment_details,B.PAYMENT_DETAILS)>0
                      )
```

but this also did not return any results as expected. What would be the best way to go about this?
Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I am using the below query to identify the results, however they are not consistent with what I am looking for. Table A has transactions, Table B has "Payment_Details". The "Payment_Details" should not exist anywhere in column "payment_details" in Table C.

My results are returning some records where a particular customer has a payment_details (from Table B) with certain text in the "payment_details" in Table C. I only want records where the payment_details for each record in Table B are nowhere in the entire Table C, so it appears the logic is picking up more records than it should.

I am currently using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a.CUSTOMER), a.REF_NO, a.TRAN_TYPE,
        a.ACCT_NO, a.AMOUNT, a.AUTH_DATE,
        b.ORDERING_CUST, b.PAYMENT_DETAILS
FROM TRANSFER_HIS A
INNER JOIN TRANSFER_EXTEND_HIS B
ON A.REF_NO = B.REF_NO
INNER JOIN payroll_class c
ON charindex(c.payment_details, b.PAYMENT_DETAILS) = 0
WHERE A.CUSTOMER IS NOT NULL
and A.AUTH_DATE > '2015-05-01'
and A.TRAN_TYPE = 'ACH'
```

How can I enhance the query to NOT pull ANY records where the payment_details match between table B and table C.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution. Your schema wasn't entirely obvious, so I had to guess at some of this. If this doesn't work for you, please post your schema, as well as a reduced version of the query and some sample inputs and expected outputs.

```
select distinct
    P.*
from
    P,
    B
where
    CHARINDEX(P.payment_details, B.PAYMENT_DETAILS) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added an update to my question for clarification and posted my current query. Hopefully this helps in resolving the issue...